# Taking input from user and then naming a .txt and a .csv file based on what they say

Tags: python, file, csv

So I am trying to make something where a user is prompted to enter a keyword and then my program will take that input and return tweets including that using twitter api.  I also want it to be able to name a file after what they input.  Lets say they enter "iphone", I would like it to make a iphone.txt and iphone.csv file.  Here is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working.

By the way, the 'newFile' line should be a .txt file and the 'with open(query, 'rb') as input_file' should also be a .txt.  The other is a .csv

```
try:
    query = sys.argv[1]
except IndexError:
    query = raw_input("Choose a keyword to find the last 100 tweets about: ")

newFile = open(query, 'w').write(txt.encode('utf8'))


with open(query, 'rb') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter='\n', quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE)

    with open(query, 'wb') as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)

        for row in reader:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

almost there, but your statement should be

`with open("%s.csv" %query, 'rb') as input_file`

and

`with open("%s.txt" %query, 'wb') as output_file`

`query` just holds the value i.e. filename, you need to add it's extensions before opening the file